# Editing the question or accepted answer to make the users read all answers for a troublesome problem

Tags: discussion, answers

I resolved my problem (and all my coworker's problems) by looking at the very depth of the following post:

[Eclipse Bug: Unhandled event loop exception No more handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594590/eclipse-bug-unhandled-event-loop-exception-no-more-handles)

Edit : most of the answers provide solution since this problem can come from many sources, they just didn't applied to me.

I wanted to add an edit to the question or the answer to motivate others to read; however I'm not sure how to do it or even if it is a good idea.

In my case the answer that solved my problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20326601/5070577), and even more specifically the comments are even better.

I don't think that adding a new answer is a good idea and was thinking if I could do more than just upvoting.

How should I(/we ?) proceed?

Comment: Are the other answers objectively *wrong*? Or did they simply not apply to your case? If the former, it's reasonable to add a warning into the current top answer itself. If the latter… not much you can or should do, it's up to each seeker of knowledge to dig until they find the solution best suited for them.

Comment: They didn't apply to my case, I edited to add the clarification.

Comment: If the problem is so broad that many different solutions may apply, it's possibly too broad a question to begin with. But, well, now it has been asked, and people are finding solutions in the existing answers, so it's counterproductive to rectify that problem at the source. *Ideally* the question itself should be broken up into more narrowly defined questions, if that's possible. Alternatively, one canonical answer which covers all possible cases should be written (there are examples of such monster-answers around…). Consider writing that answer, possibly adding to the current accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding a bounty with the reason "reward existing answer" and a custom message pointing people to the right place. Sure, it will only last for seven days (unless you put it up again once it expires), but a) the additional exposure, and additional directedness, can be of significant value to the answer during those seven days, allowing it to very likely catch up a fair bit in score; and b) the blue indicator by the answer is an excellent lasting sign of something arguably more important than a mere green checkmark.

Comment: damn how could I forgot it. I will put a bounty and will validate it in 24h, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's the reader's *own responsibility* to look further than the first two answers. The only thing you can do is upvote the answer which was helpful to you (and ask your co-workers with the same problem to do the same) – if enough people do so, it will rise to the top eventually. Remember that for *other* users, the first or second answer may already solve their problem. In fact, given the number of upvotes, that's *very likely* to be the case.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. This error can come from many sources, so pretty much all those answers work for some, and did not work for others. Usually when I red answers on SO or others place, the bottom of them (when there are lot of answers) are full or 'did not solved my problem' or useless facts. So yes when I see a lot of answers, I usually skip the very bottom of them, and I think I'm far from behing the only one. ANd considering the number of vote needed to catch up I was thinking of something else, but maybe that wasn't a good idea.